# How to easily enable/disable Chrome/Eclipse debugger?

Tags: php, linux, eclipse, google-chrome, xdebug

I am using Google Chrome, Eclipse 2020 to Xdebug PHP on Manjaro Linux. I don't want Eclipse to run the debugger every time I need to check the script. Is there a way (an easy way) to disable Xdebug and re-enable it every time I want? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use one of the browser extensions, as is explained in the Xdebug documentation: http://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#web-application

You can just toggle whether Xdebug needs to initiate a request or not. The IDE needs to be in "listen mode", although I am not sure whether this is something that Eclipse supports. PhpStorm and the Xdebug plugin for VS Code do.

Comment: Unfortunately Eclipse doesn't support "listen mode" as far as I've delved into it and I have used Xdebug Helper but it doesn't seem to work. I miss PhpStorm so much but Eclipse is all my company is supplying me right now. Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid you then can't make this with Eclipse and Xdebug then. Sorry. FWIW, VS Code is a free IDE and has an Xdebug plugin, so maybe you can try that?